# How to find all possible consecutive and not overlapping sublists with minimum length of 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-series, data-science, sublist

What i actually want to do is to fit all possible straight lines in some data and find the best group of fitted lines by measuring their average R squared.

The step that i got stuck, is how to obtain with a sufficient method all those possible sublists so that i can make the fit afterwards. That's also the reason why i want a minimum length of 3 because every line that passes through two points has a perfect fit and i don't want that.

For example my first try was something like that:

```
def sub_lists(lst):
    lr = [lst[:i] for i in range(3,len(lst)-2)]
    rl = [lst[i:] for i in range(len(lst)-3,2,-1)]
    return [[lr[i], rl[-i-1]] for i in range(len(lr))]

>>> tst = [489, 495, 501, 506, 508, 514, 520, 522]
>>> sub_lists(tst)
[[[489, 495, 501], [506, 508, 514, 520, 522]],
[[489, 495, 501, 506], [508, 514, 520, 522]],
[[489, 495, 501, 506, 508], [514, 520, 522]]]
```

but then i came across the below list with a length of 5 and it didn't work.Thus the expected output would be just the list:

```
>>> tst = [489, 495, 501, 506, 508]
>>> sub_lists_revised(tst)
[489, 495, 501, 506, 508]
```

and following the same logic when i have a bigger length of data, like 10 for example:

```
>>> tst = [489, 495, 501, 506, 508, 514, 520, 525, 527, 529]
>>> sub_lists_revised(tst)
# the whole list
[489, 495, 501, 506, 508, 514, 520, 525, 527, 529]
# all possible pairs
[[[489, 495, 501], [506, 508, 514, 520, 525, 527, 529]],
[[489, 495, 501, 506], [508, 514, 520, 525, 527, 529]],
[[489, 495, 501, 506, 508], [514, 520, 525, 527, 529]],
[[489, 495, 501, 506, 508, 514], [520, 525, 527, 529]],
[[489, 495, 501, 506, 508, 514, 520], [525, 527, 529]]]
# and finally, all possible triplets which i couldn't figure out
[[[489, 495, 501], [506, 508, 514], [520, 525, 527, 529]],
[[489, 495, 501], [506, 508, 514, 520], [525, 527, 529]],
[[489, 495, 501, 506], [508, 514, 520], [525, 527, 529]]]
```

So to conclude, what i want is a general approach that will work for even more data, although i don't think i would really need more than triplets at the moment.

I also add the figures from the first example after the fit: [fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LFwK.png), [fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tseKB.png), 
 [fig3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugTTe.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it recursively.

The first function generates the possible cut points for a list of length `n` producing sublists of length 3 at least.

The second one just yields the sublists, cut according to the cutting points.

Both are generators, so the sublists get produced on the fly, one at a time, if you use them in a loop. That might be useful as the number of possible sublists can grow very high when your data gets longer.

```
def cut_points(n, already_cut=None):
    # The first cut point is at 0 
    if already_cut is None:
        already_cut = [0]

    # We can cut at all places between the last cut plus 3 
    # and the length minus 3, and yield recursively the solutions for each choice
    for i in range(already_cut[-1]+3, n-2):
        cuts = already_cut[:] + [i]
        yield from cut_points(n, cuts)

    # When we tried all cut points and reached the total length, we yield the cut points list 
    yield already_cut[:] + [n]


def all_possible_sublists(data):
    n = len(data)
    for cut in cut_points(n):
        yield [data[cut[i]:cut[i+1]] for i in range(len(cut)-1)]
```

Some tests:

```
list(all_possible_sublists([0, 1, 2, 3]))
# [[[0, 1, 2, 3]]]

list(all_possible_sublists([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
# [[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]],
#  [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
#  [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]]

for sublist in all_possible_sublists([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]):
    print(sublist)
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
# [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```